# Printing Concentric Squares of Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been practicing patterns until I reached this pattern. It says print concentric squares of numbers with max layer as `NxN` and Min layer `1x1`

```
   For instance, for input N=3 the desired 
    o/p should be 

   33333
   32223
   32123
   32223
   33333
```

I tried like

```
     for(int i=1;i<=2*N-1;i++)   
         { 
              for(int j=1;j<=2*N-1;j++) 
            {
    if(i==1 || i==N) --for max n min layer
             System.out.print(N);
else if(j!=1 || j!=N) --for col not as max n min and rows between max n min
             System.out.print(N-1);
             else 
                 System.out.print(N);
               }}
```

I know that its wrong but I want it to be solved in a conventional way as above sample meaning step by step.

Comment: Try to perform the algorithm step by step with pen and paper. This way you can see where it does something different than what you intended (some debug-output can also help to see, where things go wrong).

Comment: These are circles according to the *maximum norm*. This may help you finding a simple formula

Comment: @MrSmith42 I did gave it a try by solving it via algos but the pattern doesnt fall in sync so likewise asked.

Answer (score 0):

These are circles according to the *maximum norm*.

According to this distance, two points of coordinates `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` are at distance

```
d = max (abs(x0-x1), abs(y0-y1))
```

Here, the first step is to calculate the coordinates of the centre. Assuming `N` is odd and indices from `1` to `N`, we get:

```
(xc, yc) = ((N+1)/2, (N+1)/2)
```

Then, for each point of coordinates `(i, j)`, you simply have to print

```
1 + max (abs(i-xc), abs(j-yc))
```

Note that I call `N` the total number of rows and columns

Pseudo-code:

```
N = 5
do i = 1 to N
    do j = 1 to N
        print 1 + max(abs(i-(N+1)/2), abs(j-(N+1)/2))
    print "\n"
```

Comment: dont you think this is way too broad than what the problem's ask is ? Nice try though.

Comment: Why do you think it is too broad? You will exactly get the expected result with very few lines, using the definition of a circle

Comment: If you can post some code for the same logic, thatll help i guess.

Comment: I don't know java well. I   have edited with a simple pseudo-code

Comment: i'll do test this in a while but I am still not sure will this work or not.

Comment: sure, in a while.

Comment: Note that I corrected a typo in the pseude-code, `N+1` instead of `N-1`. The calculation of the center was correct in the text. I checked the code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and you can change the below code according to your requirement

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int size = 2*n-1;
    int start=0;
    int end=size-1;
    int [][]a = new int[size][size];
while(n!=0) {
    for (int i=start;i<=end;i++) {
        for (int j=start;j<=end;j++) {
            if((i==start)||(j==start)||(i==end)||(j==end))
                a[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    start++;
    end--;
    n--;
}
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For ith row (i < N), starting from N, you are printing elements N to N-i (excluding N-i)

Then for 2*(N-i)-1 times, you are printing N-i

In the end, you are printing N-i to N (again excluding N-i)

Printing these rows twice will do the trick

Sample code is as follows. (This is just to give you an Idea. Not tested):

```
for(int k = -N+1; k <= N-1; k++) {
    int i = N-1 - Math.abs(k);
    for(int j = N; J > N-i; j--){
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    for(int j = 0; J < 2*(N-i)-1; j++){
        System.out.print(N-i);
    }
    for(int j = N-i+1; J <= N; j++){
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The pattern is like first and last row be the max N then each time a row reduces the N gets reduced by that ith row and likewise each time a column reduces then the value also gets reduces by that jth column as (N-j) this happens when columns value is less than N and if greater than (N+j) likewise. Somewhat the logic rolls around this but seems a lot difficult to implement. I guess your program wont work as per your logic though.

Comment: As per the logic above, i will be 0 for first and last row, 1 for 2nd and last but one row and so on
In the inner loops, 
For i = 0
first loop will run 0 times
second loop runs 2*N-1 times printing N
third loop runs 0 times

For i = 1,
first loop will run 1 times printing N
second loop runs 2*N-3 times printing N-1
third loop runs 1 times printing N

For i = 2,
first loop will run 2 times printing N and N-1
second loop runs 2*N-5 times printing N-2
third loop runs 2 times printing N-1 and N

Let me know if I have faltered anywhere