# Pattern print from a given single integer

Tags: arrays, c

Given a number — 4 — I have to output

4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4

The main code I wrote has an error for direction.  According to me, I wrote the correct code, but it only works for 1 and 3 and loops between it — 1 3 1 3 1 3.... it is supposed to work 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1.... accordingly in a spiral manner. I would really appreciate if you could help me!

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
int main() 
{

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int x=n+(n-1);
    int size=x*x;
    int t,b,l,r;
    t=0;l=0;
    b=x-1;
    r=x-1;
    int i,j;
    int res[size];
    int index=0;
    int dir=0;
   
   
    while(t<=b && l<=r){
        if(dir==0){
            for(i=l;i<r;i++){
                res[index]=n;
                index++;
            }
            t++;
            dir=1;
        }
        else if (dir==1) {
            for(i=t;i<b;i++){
                res[index]=n;
                index++;
            }
            r--;
            dir=2;
        }
        else if (dir==2) {
            for(i=r;i>l;i--){
                res[index]=n;
                index++;
            }
            b--;
            dir=3;
        }
        else if(dir==3){
            for(i=b;i>l;i++){
                res[index]=n;
                index++;
            }
            l++;
            dir=0;
        }
        n--;
        dir=(dir+1)%4;
        // printf("%d",dir); if u want to check 
    }
    /* yet to proceed 
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(j=i;j<x;j=j+x){
            
            printf("%d ",res[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Would you mind choosing one?

Comment: @MikeCAT https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info "A question should be tagged with c only, if: - It contains pure C, with no trace of C++, or questions with code that could be either language." /--/ "If you encounter a post with both tags, edit/re-tag it if needed according to the above rules. If you can tell the language by reading the posted code, simply edit tags accordingly. Avoid prompting the user "is it C or C++?" in comments unless the question is truly unclear."

Comment: About same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983702/10553341. Note: it is not a duplicate, not in C, no upvoted or accepted answers. However the pseudocode I provided works.

Comment: Your code is way too compilcated for that simple problem. Checkout @Damien's linked answer. The pseudocode is quite short and should yield an easy solution. I might write it up  in C as an answer here.

Comment: @Lundin I concluded that the language is unclear because many C program can also be compiled as C++ and this code doesn't contain C-only things like `int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));`. Looling carefully after reading your comment, `int main()` looks like C++ code. `int main(void)` is better in C. On the other hand, omitting header is actually C-specific, but many (bad, in my view) C++ questions also don't include required headers.

Comment: @Lundin Looking more carefully, VLA is used and it is not in the standard C++. But some C++ compilers support that.

Comment: @MikeCAT If the OP doesn't mention compiler and there's no trace of C++, then tag it C only. And indeed VLA ought to mean this is C. The most important thing here is that we shouldn't needlessly be bothering those only following the C++ tag with this question, or needlessly bother those who only follow the C tag with C++ questions.

Comment: Does your assignment explicitely ask for arrays? Your solution might be much simpler without them.

Comment: "According to me, I wrote the correct code" but according to the computer, you didn't.

Comment: What I could come up with: https://godbolt.org/z/9oT7o8